# How to change iframe scrolling property in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this code in an ASPX page:

```
<iframe height="78%" width="100%" id="ifrmReport" scrolling="auto" name="ifrmReport" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I want to change this property in javascript or jQuery: `scrolling="none"` or `"auto"` based on certain condition. Can anybody help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the `attr()` or `prop()` methods to achieve this:

```
$('#ifrmReport').prop('scrolling', 'none');
// or
$('#ifrmReport').attr('scrolling', 'none');
```

Comment: i get member not found error when i use $('#ifrmReport').attr('scrolling', 'none')

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy.

**jQuery**

```
if (condition===true) {
   jQuery("iframe#id").attr("scrolling", "none");
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
if (condition===true) {
   document.querySelector("iframe#id").setAttribute("scrolling", "none");
}
```